# Image responsive in bootstrap to fill column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a bootstrap column defined as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-4 limit">
    <img id="myImage" src="" class="img-responsive"/>
</div>

<style>
    .limit {
        max-height:500px;
        overflow:hidden;  
    }
</style>
```

The source of the image is obtained programatically so I do not know in advance the height or width of my image. What I want to do is that the image in this column whose height is limited appear completely inside of the div. With the `img-responsive` class I have achieved the image to horizontally fill my column, however, as this class also sets the height to auto, most of the time this causes the image to overflow and be hidden. I do not want my image to overflow in any way.

So, lets say that my column measures:

- Width: 300px (defined by bootstrap)
- Height: 500px (.limit)

And my image dimensions are:

- Width: 600px
- Height: 1500px

The current configuration makes the image shrink to 300px x 750px. As its container is set to only 500px, this causes the last 250px to be lost inside the overflow. I would like to image instead to be resized to 200px x 500px in order for it to completely into the containing div

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="limit">
            <img src="images/yourimage.png" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .limit{
        width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
    .limit img{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
     }
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks. However I do not need to set the width of the limit div because this is controlled by bootstrap. Also, changed the img class to max-width and max-height.

.limit {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        max-height:500px;
        overflow:hidden;  
    }
     .limit img {
         max-width: 100%;
         max-height: 100%;
     }

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inherit the height or the width of the parent div (as both would not contain proportions). This could only work if you have the same type of img (all portret or landscape).  Other solution is to calculate the dimensions based on the max width/height of the img in your program language. Pick the one that matches the condition (both var  <= max value). Then echo the solution in your html.

Answer (score 0):

@Luis Becerril I normally used this plugin with those type of issues. Please try this. If may suit to your requirement. [jQuery Image Center](http://boxlight.github.io/bl-jquery-image-center/)

Comment: Very handy plugin! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way in Bootstrap 4

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="images/yourimage.png" alt="" class="w-100" />
    </div>
</div>
```